# functions in opencv_contrib are missing from cv2.so?

Tags: python, opencv

in opencv3.0-dev most nonfree stuff have been move to opencv_contrib. I've built it with opencv_contrib. All xfeatures2d tests have been passed.

However, the cv2 still does not have the SIFT() or SURF(), etc. The old trick of BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT does not work now. It said:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT
```

Can any one tell me which flag I should use to enable it?

Does it has anything to do with following code I found in modules/python/common.cmake

```
# module blacklist
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_cud(a|ev)")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_adas$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_face$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_matlab$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_tracking$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_optflow$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_bgsegm$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_xfeatures2d$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_ximgproc$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_xphoto$")
ocv_list_filterout(candidate_deps "^opencv_ts$")

ocv_add_module(${MODULE_NAME} BINDINGS OPTIONAL ${candidate_deps})

ocv_module_include_directories(
    "${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}"
    ${PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/src2"
    )
```

It seems like all the extra modules get blacklisted?!

Oh, seems like after commit 31df47b6eaeb753a77f4d0cc3f4225c5c40682f6, most of the opencv_contrib have been blacklisted.

So I guess if I want to use python, I should not use opencv 3.0 at all.

Comment: Commenting to follow this as I have a similar issue, no SIFT in 3.0.0 with contrib moddules

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have `xfeatures2d` submodules inside `cv2`: type `help(cv2)`.

You can also check the description of this submodules by `help(cv2.xfeatures2d)`

Now try `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` to create a SIFT obj. 
Then use `kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img,None)` to extract keypoint and desc.